# Cosmic Encounter Can I attack an empty planet

Tags: cosmic-encounter

We had a disagreement about this the last time I played. The rules seem to allude that you can attack an empty planet in an encounter with another player but it doesn't seem to be made explicit.

Example: Green has 4 colonies in his home system, one planet is empty. If blue draws a green destiny card can he attack the empty planet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, as long as the planet is still there.

The defender defends as normal (playing an encounter card) but with no ships. From [the rules](http://daveola.com/CosmicEncounter/Rules/Fantasy-Flight.pdf) on **Launch** (page 8):

> Note that, in a home system, the defense may not
>   have any ships on the targeted planet, in which case he or she
>   defends the planet with zero ships.

If green were to draw a green destiny card, they could attack their own empty planet to reestablish a colony (or they could draw another destiny card). Page 7:

> When drawing his or her own color, if a player has a home
>   planet with no ships on it at all (enemy or otherwise), then he
>   or she may aim the hyperspace gate at that planet to automatically
>   re-establish a colony there with up to four ships from
>   other colonies. Doing so counts as a successful encounter.

Answer (score 6):

You absolutely can attack a planet with no defenders.

On page 8 of [the rulebook](http://daveola.com/CosmicEncounter/Rules/Fantasy-Flight.pdf) it states:

> **Defending with Nothing?**
>
> Even though a player may no longer have a colony
> on one of his or her home planets, that player
> must still defend it.

Which certainly confirms that you can attack an unoccupied world.